# Installed a python2.7 as an alternate, but path to default 2.6 is destroyed. System path file for default interpreter?

Tags: python, linux, centos

I installed python2.7 as an alternate version of python. I was attempting to utilize a newer version of mod_python and I needed 2.7. The default python (/bin/python) is 2.6. Unfortunately now, calling python from the command line calls /usr/local/bin/python2.7. I realize that I can set up a number of links pointing back to /bin/python--I just don't think this is a great idea. The OS (CentOS6) uses 2.6.2 by default, and I don't want the OS to use another version of python. I installed 2.7 from source, but forgot to specify 'make altinstall' rather than 'make install'. This is a semi-work related server, so I need to implement something that will permanently fix the problem. I realize .profile and .bashrc have paths for python, but these appear to be more for bash logins via ssh. I need to find a way to change the system's default python path back to 2.6.2. How would one go about doing this? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `/usr/local/bin` comes before `/bin` in your `$PATH`.

What does `which python` say? I suspect it gives a symlink `/usr/local/bin/python` to `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`. Changing that symlink to `/bin/python` or removing it altogether should fix your problem.

Comment: `which python` and `whereis python` should tell you a lot about where Python is on your path

Comment: $ which python --> /usr/local/bin/python

Comment: $ whereis python --> /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/lib/python2.6 /usr/lib64/python2.6 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python2.7-config /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python2.6 /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz

Comment: Rob and Dave, where is the actual symlink that "which" and "whereis" use? Thank you.

Comment: @user1091728, try `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python` to see where it points to. If it points to `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` as I suspected, removing it should restore your default python to `/usr/bin/python`, i.e. Python 2.6.

Comment: There is not a symlink from `/usr/local/bin/python` to `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`. Should there be? I can put a link (`/usr/local/bin/python`) back to `/usr/bin/python`, but this doesn't seem to be the most direct or safe way to do things, seeing that the link could get moved or something. Thanks.

Comment: So `/usr/local/bin/python` is just a regular file? How about `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`? Regardless, if you remove `/usr/local/bin/python`, the shell will keep searching for `python` in your `$PATH` and end up with the one in `/usr/bin/`, which would be Python 2.6.

Comment: I moved `/usr/local/bin/python`. For some reason, the OS is still looking for the `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`. `$ python` gives me this: `bash: /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory`. I agree with you totally--the shell should continue to look for python in `/usr/bin`, but it isn't doing that. There must have been a path stored somewhere when python2.7 was compiled. I don't know where to find it though. Actually, I just had a revelation... logged out and back in to source my profile and now the path is correct. I feel so dumb. Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: @user1091728, you're welcome. You can mark the answer as correct by clicking the checkmark at the left of the answer.

Comment: I had a similar problem where I installed a newer version of python, but `python -V` still gave me the old version. Logged out and logged back in, and it worked.